# Instantaneous rate of change at a point of a function tells what?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Instantaneous rate of change is defined as the slope of the tangent line at that point, but it is also said to be the rate of change of a function at that instant .

How can a point have a rate of change and what information does instantaneous rate of change even tell us about the function at that point.
I understand that instantaneous rate of change is defined as slope of the tangent. I guess it tells us about gradient of function at the point, if it's positive, negative, etc. at that point. But how does it tell the rate of the gradient? If a function is nonlinear thus it can have different derivative value i.e. different tangent at every single point. For example, the function : $$x^2$$ has different tangent at every single point. So how can the slope of a tangent tell us about the rate of change of function at that point? In other words, as rate of change tells us how much change in output of the function will be if there is a certain amount of change in the input from this point, but since $x^2$ has different derivative at every single point, we can't really use the slope of tangent at that point to tell us what the next point will be using the slope as rate of change, isn't it?

***Edit:***

What I want to know is that if it is true that derivative is just an approximation by that I don't mean to imply that it is the approximate value of the slope of tangent, I mean to say that derivative tell us the exact value of the slope of the tangent at the point but the slope value of the tangent is not entirely equal to the exact change that happens in function value w.r.t change in the input let say for example in the function: $x^2$ the slope of tangent at a point i.e. derivative at a point is $2x$ so the change in function according to this slope value at point $x$ should be $2x$ but it isn't exact, the actual change in function's value is only approximately equal to the change  that would happen in function' value if the slope is $2x$.

Answer (score 4):

I guess I get your confusion, very basic indeed but interesting. Often times until and unless we can observe something in our head, we can't come to terms with it. In your case, the picture is incomplete and thus the confusion. Let me try to paint the complete picture. Let's start from the start to the end.

> Instantaneous rate of change is defined as the slope of the tangent line at that point, but it is also said to be the rate of change of a function at that instant.

This statement is true for every smooth (continuously differentiable) function.

The **slope of a line (called secant) between any 2 points** is given by $\Delta y/\Delta x$

And the **slope of the tangent at a point** is given by $dy/dx$ (or $\delta y/\delta x$)

And the **derivative of a function** is defined as $dy/dx$ (or $\delta y/\delta x$)

Thus, *instantaneous rate of change* which is same as the **slope of the tangent line at that point** is by definition equal to the *rate of change of a function at that instant* which is the **derivative of the function at that point**.

For a smooth function, the derivative can be given by another function. In other words, for a smooth function, the slope of the tangent at any point can be given by another function. That's why for $x^2$ we have the derivative or the slope of the tangent at any point, given by $2x$.

For a discontinuous function, such as step-function, we don't have derivative defined for every point and thus the instantaneous rate of change at that point or the derivative of the function at that point is not defined.

> how can a point have a rate of change

Well it cannot! Though a collection of points that follow a certain path may have a rate of change defined for them (like if it's a smooth function).

> what information does instantaneous rate of change even tell us about the function at that point

As the words themselves imply, instantaneous rate of change tells us the rate of change at that very instant or at that vey point.

Here's where your major confusion lies, so let's look at it more deeply.

Consider this diagram:
[image: Function Secant Tangent]

Slope of line between any 2 points, $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q_1(x_2,y_2)$ $= \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}= \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$

Now, let's start to bring $y_2$ to $y_1$ and $x_2$ to $x_1$. This will cause the slope of the line in the diagram given above to follow the path from $Q_1$ to $Q_4$.

Since at any of the points we haven't yet reached the point $P$ so the slope of the line between the 2 points will give us **average rate of change between the 2 points** instead of the *instantaneous rate of change*.

Now consider a point just **next** to point $P(x,y)$, say $H(x+h, y')$. Here, $h$ is infinitesimally small, such that $h\rightarrow 0$. Now, the slope of the line between these 2 points will give us the instantaneous rate of change as after that instant we will move on the next instant/point.

Above statement is very important to understand. Point $P$ and $H$ are **actually** next to each other! (that's how we have defined). Even if you see a curve of $x^2$ on your screen and take 2 pixels that are next to each other to be lying on the curve, they are still actually not next to each other with respect to the curve as between those 2 pixels there are infinitely many points but the points that we have taken, that is, $P$ and $H$ **are** next to each other!

So the instantaneous rate of change or the derivative of the function is given by the slope of the line between the 2 points $P$ and $H$ which would have been written as $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}= \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ but since the values are too small we use the more apt representation which is given by $\frac {dy}{dx}$ or $\frac {\delta y}{\delta x}$ to be precise.

Now all that remains is the task of computing such small values for which we make the use of limits. In short, dumbguywithmathsmajor has already shown it but for clarity, I'll show it here as well. It is as follows:

$\frac {\delta y}{\delta x} = \frac{y_H-y_P}{x_H-x_P}=\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{x+h-x}$

Since, $h\rightarrow 0$, we show that and compute using limits, as: $$\frac {\delta y}{\delta x} =\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

For $x^2$ this comes out as $2x$.

> but as in function $x^2$ that have different derivative at every single point ,we can't really use the slope of tangent at that point to tell us what the next point will be using the slope as rate of change ,can we?

Finally, in this part, you are mistaken. the function $x^2$ does not have different derivative at different points. It has same derivate for any point and that is given by $2x$. Yes, the value of the derivative is different for different points. That should not be confusing though.

Consider this example: You should know that the acceleration of a body can be found out by formulating the derivative of the speed function of that body. When a ball is thrown up, the speed of the ball is represented by the function $f(x)=x^2$ and so the acceleration is given by $f'(x)=2x$. Now if you understand that it's not necessary for acceleration of a body be necessarily constant and that it can be variable too at different moments then that should settle it.

### PS:

> for example in the function: $x^2$ the slope of tangent at a point i.e. derivative at a point is $2x$ so the change in function according to this slope value at point x should be $2x$ but it isn't exact, the actual change in function's value is only approximately equal to the change that would happen in function' value if the slope is $2x$.

Here, you are gravely confused between 2 things: *rate of change* and *change*. These are not same.

Consider the following example for the given function:
$$\bf x^2$$

1. **Instantaneous rate of change** (or **Derivative**): $2x$
2. **Average rate of change**: $\frac {x_2 ^2-x_1 ^2}{x_2-x_1}=x_1+x_2$
3. **Change in value**: $x_2 ^2-x_1 ^2$

Assume 2 points: $P(5,25)$ and $Q(10,100)$

1. At $P=2\times 5=10$ and at $Q=2\times 10=20$
2. Between $P$ and $Q= 5+10=15$
3. Between $P$ and $Q= 10^2-5^2=75$

Assume 2 points: $P(5,25)$ and $R(5+10^{-10},{(5+10^{-10})}^2)$

1. At $P=2\times 5=10$ and at $R=10 + (2)10^{-10}$
2. Between $P$ and $R= 5+5+10^{-10}=10+10^{-10}$
3. Between $P$ and $R= {(5+10^{-10})}^2-5^2=10^{-20} + 10^{-9}$

***Note 1:*** As we have already established above, the average rate of change is a good approximation for instantaneous rate of change when the 2 points are *quite* close to each other.

***Note 2:*** Derivative of a function gives you the rate of change only. If from derivative you want to find the actual function, you need to integrate (still you won't get your actual function).

Comment: Good answer. But I must point out that there are a few things which are not precise in the answer. 

(1) "the derivative of the function is given by the slope of the line between the 2 points  and  which would have been written as Δ/Δ" 
the derivative is not the slope of the line between the 2 points, it's the limit of those slopes as the second point becomes closer and closer. There is a BIG difference between limit of some sequence and any particular value of that sequence.

(2) "slope of a tangent between any 2 point is given by Δ/Δ"
it should be chord not tangent

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor Thank you for the compliment. 1. Here, consider the whole sentence/para together. I have, in essence, written it's the limit but without using that word to make it less complicated and more understandable to someone who is not well-versed with it. 2. It was a mistake, thus, corrected. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @InanimateBeing I read the whole para. There are even more problems now. First of all, you have taken the coordinates of H as (x+h, y+h), which is wrong; it should be (x+h,f(x+h)). Second, once you specify the coordinates of H, then we can always find a point which lies in between P and H (ex: (x+h/2, f(x+h/2))). I get it, you want to make things simpler, but we can't compromise with our foundations in the process.

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor kindly look at the whole and not just a part. 1. Careful observation will show you that I have taken y=f(x) implicitly. 2. I have not just taken $h$ but also mentioned $h→0$ thus again invalidating your claim and no foundations have been compromised.

Comment: @InanimateBeing, I have read the whole answer. 1. I know y=f(x), even then, the coordinate of H won't be (x+h,y+h) because y+h is f(x)+h not f(x+h). 2. You can never take two real numbers next to each other, no matter what. You say P and H are next to each other, which is impossible according to the density property of real numbers. If you actually take h->0, then P and H are the same point.

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor 1. Plausible. Corrected. 2. I've taken a general approach here so your concern seems less valid to me.

Comment: The first few bits of this answer seem to assume every continuous function is differentiable, but that's false.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for pointing it out, edited.

Comment: I hope *finally* I got the things right. @ryang thanks a lot for clearing the confusion and also providing all those variants and how to see them.

Answer (score 2):

We know that, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$

$\therefore$ for small enough $h$, we can write approximately,

$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$

Clearly, the LHS of the above equation is the approximate (which becomes more and more accurate as h->$0$) rate of change of the function f at x. Derivative at any point $p$ gives the rate of change of the function at points very close to $p$. There are various numerical techniques which are based on exactly the same idea.

You can have a sequence of the rate of change of function between points $x$ and $x+h_i$, where $h_i$'s are positive and decreasing (ex: $h_i =  \frac{\Delta H}{2^i}$, for some finite $H \in \mathbb{R}^+)$, then derivative is just the limiting value of that sequence.

You can't understand what derivatives are without understanding what limits are. So I recommend learning limits first.

Now, think about how'll you define the rate of change of any function at any point $x_0$. It's really hard to define, isn't it?. But if you have 2 points, then I'm sure you won't have any issue, right?. Since we can easily define the average rate of change between 2 points, to define the instantaneous rate of change, we take 2 points and start bringing them closer and closer, and we look at how the average rate of change varies as the point comes closer and closer. **We define the limiting value of those average rates of change between 2 points as the derivative**.

What does a derivative tell us about the function?

In a sense, a derivative at a point gives you the direction in which the function will move as you move from that point infinitesimally.

Suppose you know the function value at $x_0$, and the function is continuous. Now, I ask you, can you guess the function value at $x_0 + h \space(h \in \mathbb{R}^+)$? Can you guess the answer within some error bounds? Surely no. Suppose I tell you the derivative of that function at $x_0$. Can you answer the question now? Yes, you can.

$ f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0)  + h*f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2}*f'(\epsilon) $, where $\epsilon \in (x_0, x_0 + h)$  (Taylor's theorem)

Now, there are cases where you can find bounds on the last term. Therefore, the derivative at a point helps know the function's behaviour near that point.

If you want to extrapolate the function, just knowing the $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$, then extending a straight line from $(x_0, f(x_0))$ with a slope of $f'(x_0)$ is your best chance.

Comment: Are you saying that there really isn't anything like a perfect rate of change relation but just a approximate one or there is a perfecr rate of change but within very small region around point x (by perfect rate of change i mean that change in output w.r.t change in input is the same as derivative but approximate rate of change that it is only approximately equal to derivative at point x).

Comment: Read the last para in the answer again. It seems you don't understand what limits are, I would recommend reading about limits

Comment: I am not really asking what derivative are but what they tell us about the function at that point or around that point and just to clarify :Was it correct to say that the tangent line at a point tell us about the gradient of function at the point

Comment: I think I can answer much better if I know what level of education you are at. Yes, last statement is correct.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,I'll the edit the question to add in more details about what i am asking about and I am a first year college student.

Comment: @Anuj Please take the trouble to punctuate and check for typos.  I skimmed twice and gave up trying to read because too taxing. BTW, questions on this site are meant to benefit future readers too, not just the question-asker.  Thanks!

Comment: @ryang  I 'll keep that in mind from now  .

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor ,That's what I wanted to ask about using the slope of tangent at a point to extrapolate the function,but wasn't able to put it in a nice way ,you said f'(x) is the best choice but that doesn't mean its accurate and will give exact result but only an approximate one when we use it extrapolate the functio,right?

Comment: @Anuj, yes, it won't give exact results but only an approximation (in fact, the best approximation given the information). Also, the closer you are to the point, the better will be your approximation. All of this can be thought of intuitively; you know velocity gives the speed and direction in which the body is gonna move at that instant; it can't be used to predict the position accurately at some later instant, but still, it gives you some idea. Velocity is nothing but derivative of position. get it?

Comment: @dumbguywithmathsmajor yes ,that's the answer that clear things up but you said in this comment that velocity tell us the speed and direction in which the car is going to move and also positively or else, but isn't it the same as saying  that that velocity of the car tell us that the car will move in direction 'x' from point 'a' while covering distance 'd' at every time interval of 't' ?

Comment: @Anuj it tells the speed and direction of the car at that "instant", as its the instantaneous velocity.

Comment: "In a sense, a derivative at a point gives you the direction in which the function will move as you move from that point infinitesimally." this sounds a bit off, are you trying to use the idea of gradient as a vector here?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of it is that by knowing the value of the function $f$ at $x_0$ and the derivative of the function $f$ at $x_0,$
you can construct a straight-line function through the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$
(a point on the graph of $f$) with slope equal to $f'(x_0)$
-- that is, you can construct the tangent line of the graph at that point --
and that straight-line function is the **best possible straight-line approximation** of the original function $f$ at that point.